# SSRS Formula or expression to change NaN to 0

Tags: reporting-services, expression, nan, ssrs-expression, iif-function

I am using the following expression to work out a percentage:

```
=Fields!Days.Value/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name")
```

Days.Value is showing as 0 however in a few of my results instead of reading 0% in my percentage column it is actually reading NaN (Not a Number).

Does anyone know the exact expression forumla i need and where I should paste it in my current expression to say "Where NaN is showing, put a '0' instead?"

(See image)[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about

```
=IIF(Fields!Days.Value > 0,Fields!Days.Value/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name"),0)
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this:  =IIF(Sum(Fields!TotalPrice.Value)/Sum(Fields!Orders.Value) = 0, 0, Sum(Fields!TotalPrice.Value)/Sum(Fields!Orders.Value) netted me some weird results in a text box I deemed as currency.
The answer above worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: This solution still gave me the same error.  I've answered this question with what worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

I didn't have luck with the above answers.  Here's what worked for me:

```
=IIF(Single.IsNAN(Fields!Days.Value/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name")), 0, Fields!Days.Value/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name"))
```

Answer (score 10):

I used this for similar case,

`=REPLACE(Fields!Days.Value/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name"),"NaN","0")`

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option.  It should solve the problem, and also get rid of `Infinite` responses:

```
=val(replace(Fields!Days.Value/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name"),"NaN","0"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
=IIf(Fields!Days.Value Is Nothing Or Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name") Is Nothing, 0, Fields!Days.Value / Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name"))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest & best, I think,

```
=Switch(
Fields!Days.Value/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name") = "NaN",Nothing,
Fields!Days.Value/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name") = "Infinity",Nothing,
Fields!Days.Value/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name") = "-Infinity",Nothing
)
```

You can also put a 0 instead of nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this and found that the following was easiest to do.

```
=Iif(
Fields!Days.Value.Value <> 0 AND Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name") <> 0
, Fields!Days.Value.Value/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name")
, 0
)
```

Probably not the best solution, but works.